NetworkManager Binds Wrong Interface to dnsmasq
When I configure a DNS on localhost with NetworkManager using the dnsmasq plugin, dnsmasq binds to the wrong interface 127.0.2.1@enp6s0 instead of 127.0.2.1@lo.
In my Home.nmconnection configuration, I use a local DNS resolver (dnscrypt-proxy) which listens on 127.0.2.1:53.
Previously, when I used NetworkManager without dnsmasq, everything worked fine:
cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Home.nmconnection

.....
[ipv4]
address1=192.168.1.10/24,192.168.1.1
dns=127.0.2.1;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=manual
.....

Now I configure NetworkManager to use the dnsmasq plugin. (I need dnsmasq for a wildcard address /local.site/127.0.0.1).
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/00-use-dnsmasq.conf

# This enables the dnsmasq plugin.
[main]
dns=dnsmasq

And now, I can no longer use Home.nmconnection with dns=127.0.2.1 because dnsmasq (127.0.0.1) tries to connect to dnscrypt-proxy (127.0.2.1) on the enp6s0 interface instead of the lo interface.
NetworkManager launches dnsmasq with '--enabledbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq'.
Here is what happens on dbus when I connect with Home.nmconnection:
dbus-monitor --system "interface='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq'"

method call time=1723051681.108218 sender=:1.571 -> destination=:1.573 serial=1778 path=/uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq; member=SetServersEx
   array [
   ]
method call time=1723051681.206464 sender=:1.571 -> destination=:1.573 serial=1823 path=/uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq; member=SetServersEx
   array [
      array [
         string "127.0.2.1@enp6s0"
      ]
      array [
         string "127.0.2.1@enp6s0"
         string "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa"
      ]
   ]

I haven't found any way to tell NetworkManager which interface to use for DNS.
I tried:
1. add server=127.0.2.1@lo to 01-dnsmasq.conf
cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/01-dnsmasq.conf

address=/local.site/127.0.0.1
server=127.0.2.1@lo

but in that case, the DNS resolver will always be 127.0.2.1, regardless of the selected connection profile, which is very inconvenient.
2.I also tried putting a script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-dnsmasq-dbus-fix
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$IP4_NAMESERVERS" == "127.0.2.1" ]] ; then
    gdbus call \
      --system \
      --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq \
      --object-path /uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq \
      --method org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq.SetServersEx \
      '[]'
    
    gdbus call \
      --system \
      --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq \
      --object-path /uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq \
      --method org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq.SetServersEx \
      '[["127.0.2.1@lo"], ["127.0.2.1@lo", "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa"]]'


fi

This script only partially resolves the problem.
With this script, when I start my Home.nmconnection profile, dnsmasq correctly sets 127.0.2.1@lo and DNS resolution works, but if I connect and disconnect from a VPN, for example, dnsmasq reverts to 127.0.2.1@enp6s0 and resolution stops working.
